# Yii custom validation and server side validation?

Tags: php, validation, yii

I am a new to Yii. I am making a change password page for the users. When I got to validation I am having trouble.

This is the **view**:

```
<div class="form">
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'changepassword-form',
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
    'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
    ),
)); ?>

<p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'old_pwd'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'old_pwd'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'old_pwd'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'pwd'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'pwd'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'pwd'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'pwd_repeat'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->passwordField($model, 'pwd_repeat'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'pwd_repeat'); ?>
    <p class="hint">
        Passwords must be minimum 6 characters and can contain alphabets, numbers and special characters.
    </p>
</div>


<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Change Password'); ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div><!-- form -->
```

**Model** :

```
/**
 * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
 */
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('user, pwd, status, old_pwd, pwd_repeat', 'required'),
        array('user', 'length', 'max'=>50),
        array('pwd', 'length', 'max'=>30),
        array('status', 'length', 'max'=>10),
        array('pwd','compare'),
        array('old_pwd','checkOldPassword'),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('id, user, pwd, status', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}

// FOR CHECKING IF THE PASSWORD IS VALID
public function checkOldPassword($attribute,$params)
{
    $record=Admin::model()->findByAttributes(array('pwd'=>$this->attribute));

    if($record===null){
        $this->addError($attribute, 'Invalid password');
    }
}
```

**Controller**:

```
/**
 * Change Password for users
 */
public function actionChangePassword()
{
    // renders the view file 'protected/views/site/index.php'
    // using the default layout 'protected/views/layouts/main.php'
    if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest){
        // If the user is guest or not logged in redirect to the login form
        $this->redirect(array('site/login'));
    }
    else{
        $model = new Admin;
        if(isset($_POST['Admin'])){

            $model->attributes=$_POST['Admin'];

            $this->render('changepassword',array('model'=>$model));
        }
        else{
            $this->render('changepassword',array('model'=>$model));
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the custom validator '**checkOldPassword**' for checking the current password of the user. Now the problem is that **the custom validation is not working**. Also if I turn off javascript **I found that server side validation errors are also not displaying**. Iam new to Yii. So please pardon any stupid mistakes.
Please help.

Comment: @Jon  The custom validator is not displaying any errors. Also when I disable Javascript in my browser it doesn't display any validation errors, not even for the validation rules other than the custom validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    public $pwd_repeat;
    public $old_pwd;

    return array(
    array('old_pwd,pwd_repeat,pwd','safe'),
        array('user, pwd, status, old_pwd, pwd_repeat', 'required'),
        array('user', 'length', 'max'=>50),
        array('pwd', 'length', 'max'=>30),
        array('status', 'length', 'max'=>10),
        array('pwd','compare'),
        array('old_pwd','checkOldPassword'),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('id, user, pwd, status', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}

// FOR CHECKING IF THE PASSWORD IS VALID
public function checkOldPassword($attribute,$params)
{
    $record=Admin::model()->findByAttributes(array('pwd'=>$this->attributes['old_pwd']));

    if($record===null){
        $this->addError($attribute, 'Invalid password');
    }
}

public function actionChangePassword()
{
    // renders the view file 'protected/views/site/index.php'
    // using the default layout 'protected/views/layouts/main.php'
    if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest){
        // If the user is guest or not logged in redirect to the login form
        $this->redirect(array('site/login'));
    }
    else{
        $model = new Admin;
        if(isset($_POST['Admin'])){

            $model->attributes=$_POST['Admin'];
            $model->save();
            $this->render('changepassword',array('model'=>$model));
        }
        else{
            $this->render('changepassword',array('model'=>$model));
        }
    }
}
```

Though Still your approch is not good...**But First get it working..**

Comment: I wrote your approach is not good bcz You're checking it any user has the entered password and if is you are resetting the same...instead what you should do is first get the password of the logged-in user and if it is same as the one input from user..then reset it..You can use either $this->$attribute or $this->attributes['old_pwd'] or $this->old_pwd

Comment: Thank you for that pointer. But the thing is that this is for a simple backend system and there is only one admin user. That is why I checked if the password exists in the db and not the username.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// FOR CHECKING IF THE PASSWORD IS VALID
public function checkOldPassword($attribute,$params)
{
    $record=Admin::model()->findByAttributes(array('pwd'=>$this->pwd));

    if($record===null){
        $this->addError($attribute, 'Invalid password');
    }
}
```

replace *$this->attribute* to *$this->pwd*

Comment: I tried the following too. Even that didn't work. I think something else is seriously wrong.

'public function checkOldPassword($attribute,$params){ 
      $this->addError($attribute, 'Invalid password');
}'

Answer (score 0):

First I believe that clientValidation will not work because you are checking old password so you need server side validation(Ajax Validation). clientValidation is good for checking password length and etc.

so put this line:
'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,

Second I would change your code to something like this:

```
public function checkOldPassword($attribute,$params)
{
    $record = $this->find(array(
                'select' => 'old_password',
                'condition' => 'username=:username',
                'params' => array(':username' => $username//or user or w/e ur gonna find user),
                    ));

if($record===null){
    $this->addError($attribute, 'Invalid password');
}
else {

 if($this->old_password != $record->old_password) {

 $this->addError('old_password', "Invalid Password");
}
 }
}
```